# Mean Average Precision python code

Tags: python, scikit-learn, recommender-system

How do you compute MAP in python for evaluating recommender system effectiveness? Is there any library in sklearn or code in python for it?

I would like to compute the effectiveness of my Recommender System by computing Mean Average Precision.

Answer (score 5):

This library called **[Metrics](https://github.com/benhamner/Metrics)** provides most of metrics for Machine Learning including MAP for Recommendation systems. If you only interested in metrics for recommendation systems, perhaps you can see [this library](https://github.com/statisticianinstilettos/recmetrics).

Comment: Can i get proper implementation with python code.I am not able to get any references for it?

Comment: That library I recommended has all python implementation, what do you mean? have you checked those github pages? Click on "Metrics", or 'this library" and you see.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ml_metrics library. For install this library use:

```
pip install ml_metrics

import ml_metrics 

ml_metrics.mapk(actual, predicted, k)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the Mean Average Precision for binary classification ? In this case, the Average Precision for a list `L` of size N is the mean of the precision@k for k from 1 to N where `L[k]` is a True Positive. Is there any (open source) reliable implementation ?
In the library mentioned in the thread, I couldn't any implementation of this metric, according to my definition above.